# On analytic function with $f(e^z)=z$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Show that there does not exist any function $f$ which is analytic in $\mathbb C$ minus a (denumerable) set of *isolated singularities* and such that $f(e^z)=z$ wherever $f(e^z)$ is defined.

---

**My attempt**:

Suppose $w_0\ne 0$ is an **isolated** singularity of $f$, then for every sequence $\{z_n\}$ in the domain of $f$, such that $e^{z_n}\to w_0$ ($e^{z_n}$ can take any value in the nbhd of $w_0$ since we can choose an analytic branch of $\ln w_0$ for each $w_0\ne 0$) and $f(e^{z_n})=z_n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=w$ and we conclude that $f$ can only have an isolated singularity at $z=0$.

Now note that $f(e^1)=1$ and $f(e^{2\pi i})=2\pi i$ but $e^1=e^{2\pi i}$ which is a contradiction.

Is that correct?

---

**Edit:**

I think the main idea of this question is that we have to take a branch cut along $[0,\infty]$ to make $f$ well-defined, otherwise it is nonsense to claim $f(e^z)=z$ as was pointed out in my attempt above.

On the other hand, $f$ is forced to exist other than a set with *isolated singularities* which is unrealistic, since $[0,\infty]$ does not consist of isolated points.

Comment: Note that $e^= e \ne 1 = e^{2 \pi i}$. It's a good idea to use that the exponential function is periodic with period $2 \pi i$. But what if $f(e^1)$ or $f(e^{2 \pi i})$ is not defined? Can you guarantee that there is a point $z$ such that both $f(e^z)$ and $f(e^{z + 2 \pi i})$ are defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma: Suppose $C\subset \mathbb R$ is countable. Let $E=\mathbb R \setminus C.$ Then there exists $t_1,t_2\in E$ such that $t_2=t_1+2\pi.$

Proof: If not, then the uncountable set $\{t+2\pi: t\in E\}$ is a subset of the countable set $C,$ contradiction.

Now to the problem: Suppose we have such an $f.$ Let $D$ be the denumerable set of singularities of $f.$ Write $g(z)=e^z.$ Then $g^{-1}(D)$ is countable, so we can write this set as $\{x_1+iy_1,x_2+iy_2,\dots\}.$

Let $C=\{y_1,y_2,\dots\}$ and $E=\mathbb R \setminus C.$ The lemma then gives $t_1,t_2\in E$ such that $t_2=t_1+2\pi.$ This implies the horizontal lines $\{s+it_1:s\in \mathbb R\}$ and $\{s+i(t_1+2\pi):s\in \mathbb R\}$ both miss $g^{-1}(D).$ Thus $f\circ g$ is defined on both of these lines. We then have

$$s+it_1 =(f\circ g)(s+it_1)$$ $$ = (f\circ g)(s+i(t_1+2\pi))=s+i(t_1+2\pi)$$

for all $s,$ contradicition.

Comment: There is a contradiction because $s+it_1=s+i(t_1+2\pi)$ so $s+it_1=s+it_1+2\pi$ so $0=2\pi$?

Comment: @manooooh Right, or simply $a+ib=c+id$ iff $a=c,b=d.$

Comment: I think you may want to explain why $g^{-1}(D)$ is countable and how you get this from $D$ being denumerable. Also, have you taken a branch cut regarding the preimage of $D$? Since it may not be well-defined.

Comment: If $U$ is open and connected and $g:U\to \mathbb C$ is analytic and nonconstant, then for every $w\in \mathbb C,$ $g^{-1}(\{w\})$ is a subset of $U$ with no limit points in $U$ (identity principle). Hence $g^{-1}(\{w\})$ is countable. It follows that if $D$ is countable, so is $g^{-1}(D).$ Note that we are talking about preimages here; these are always defined, even for the wackiest functions. I am not claiming $g$ has an inverse function. I am not sure why you bring up branch cuts in the case $g(z)=e^z,$ since I am not trying to define an inverse function of $e^z$ in any sense.

Comment: PS: In the case of $g(z)=e^z,$ you can directly verify $g^{-1}(\{w\})$ is countably infinite ($w\ne 0$), or is empty ($w=0$).

Comment: @zhw. Now I see. I didn't know the meaning of "denumerable" and I took it as a synonym as "uncountable" by mistaken... Thank you!